# ionic - login page not redirecting to main page

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

This is happening only when login page is used as fallback. Same login page is working fine when main page is used as fallback. I'm very new to this framework and any help for fixing this would be much appreciated. Please feel free to ask if you need any other code for solving this. Thanks in advance!

Here is my config,

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider

    .state('app', {
    url: '/app',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/menu.html'
})

.state('app.login', {
    url: '/login',
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
            controller: 'AppCtrl'
        }
    },
    authenticate: false
})

.state('app.search', {
    url: '/search',
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/search.html',
            controller: 'mainCtrl'
        }
    }
})

.state('app.browse', {
        url: '/browse',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/browse.html',
                controller: 'mainCtrl'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('app.playlists', {
        url: '/playlists',
        views: {
            'menuContent': {
                templateUrl: 'templates/playlists.html',
                controller: 'PlaylistsCtrl'
            }
        }
    })

.state('app.snapshot', {
    url: '/snapshot',
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/snapshot.html'
        }
    }
})

.state('app.callqueues', {
    url: '/callqueues',
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/callqueues.html'
        }
    }
})

.state('app.single', {
    url: '/playlists/:playlistId',
    views: {
        'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/playlist.html',
            controller: 'PlaylistCtrl'
        }
    }
});
// if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
//   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/search');
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/login');
});
```

This is my loginCtrl(login controller),

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', [])

.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout, $location, $http, $log, $state) {

// With the new view caching in Ionic, Controllers are only called
// when they are recreated or on app start, instead of every page change.
// To listen for when this page is active (for example, to refresh data),
// listen for the $ionicView.enter event:
//$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(e) {
//});

// Form data for the login modal
$scope.loginData = {};

// Create the login modal that we will use later
// $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/login.html', {
//     scope: $scope
// }).then(function(modal) {
//     $scope.modal = modal;
// });

// Triggered in the login modal to close it
// $scope.closeLogin = function() {
//     $scope.modal.hide();
// };

// Open the login modal
// $scope.login = function() {
//     $scope.modal.show();
// };

$scope.chartConfig = {
    options: {
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [10, 15, 12, 8, 7]
    }],
    title: {
        text: 'Hello'
    },

    loading: false
};

// Perform the login action when the user submits the login form
$scope.doLogin = function() {
    console.log('Doing login', $scope.loginData);
    var username = $scope.loginData.name;
    var password = $scope.loginData.password;
    console.log("username" + $scope.loginData.name);
    if (username == "admin@as" && password == "admin") {
        console.log("if part");
        $location.path("#/app/search");
    } else {
        console.log("error");
        // $("#errorpwd").css({"display":"block"});
        // $scope.message = "Error";
        // $scope.messagecolor = "alert alert-danger";
    }
    // Simulate a login delay. Remove this and replace with your login
    // code if using a login system
    // $timeout(function() {
    //     $scope.closeLogin();
    // }, 1000);
};
})
```

and finally this is my login html code,

```
<ion-view view-title="Login" name="login-view">
<ion-header-bar class="bar bar-header bar-positive">
    <h1 class="title">Login</h1>
    <!--<button class="button button-clear button-primary icon-left ion-close-circled" ng-click="modal.hide()"></button>-->
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-content>
    <form ng-submit="doLogin()">
        <div class="list">
            <label class="item item-input">
      <span class="input-label">Username</span>
      <input type="text" ng-model="loginData.name">
    </label>
            <label class="item item-input">
      <span class="input-label">Password</span>
      <input type="password" ng-model="loginData.password">
    </label>
            <label class="item">
      <button nav-clear class="button button-block button-positive" type="submit">Log in</button>
    </label>
        </div>
    </form>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have not injected ui-router as a dependency to the module,

```
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['ui.router']);
```

also refer the js for the ui.router

```
 <!-- Angular -->
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <!-- UI-Router -->
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out @sajeetharan. I just tried changing "$location.path()" to "$state.go()" and to my surprise it is working like a charm. I appreciate your answer though.